# MQTT - Java Application Cannot see published message

Tags: java, mqtt, mosquitto

I am working on an MQTT application in eclipse. I was earlier using mqtt-dashboard as the public broker and was able to see the messages that I was publishing on the dashboard. For some reason, this site is down so I switched to mosquitto. My code is same but still I am not able to publish messages to this broker. My code is as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String topic        = "home automation systems";
    String content      = "I am a test message";
    int qos             = 2;
    String broker       = "tcp://test.mosquitto.org:1883";
    String clientId     = "home automation";
    MemoryPersistence persistence = new MemoryPersistence();
    try {
            MqttClient sampleClient = new MqttClient(broker, clientId, persistence);
            MqttConnectOptions connOpts = new MqttConnectOptions();
            connOpts.setCleanSession(true);
            System.out.println("Connecting to broker: "+broker);
            sampleClient.connect(connOpts);
            System.out.println("Connected");
            System.out.println("Publishing message: "+content);
            MqttMessage message = new MqttMessage(content.getBytes());
            message.setQos(qos);
            sampleClient.publish(topic, message);
            System.out.println("Message published");
            sampleClient.disconnect();
            System.out.println("Disconnected");
            System.exit(0);
        } 
        catch(MqttException me) {
            System.out.println("reason "+me.getReasonCode());
            System.out.println("msg "+me.getMessage());
            System.out.println("loc "+me.getLocalizedMessage());
            System.out.println("cause "+me.getCause());
            System.out.println("excep "+me);
            me.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

}

I am trying to see the published message on this dashboard: http://test-mosquitto.herokuapp.com/
but cannot see my message. Please correct me if I am missing something. I am new to it. Thanks.

Comment: Could you help me to solve this problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50111933/mosquitto-java-broker-is-showing-error-exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-run

Answer (score 0):

If you expect a message to show up on that "dashboard", it would need to be published with the retained flag set - that web app can only show retained messages, not regular ephemeral ones.

Comment: I am not familiar with retained and ephemeral messages. Is it a concept related to MQTT?

Comment: Yes, retained messages are a feature of MQTT.