# Mosquitto java broker is showing error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't locate the resource "config/moquette.conf"

Tags: java, mqtt

I want to experiment ‘mqtt’ protocol. For this I have downloaded necessary file explained in this link http://www.hascode.com/2016/06/playing-around-with-mqtt-and-java-with-moquette-and-eclipse-paho/.

Code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import io.moquette.interception.AbstractInterceptHandler;
import io.moquette.interception.InterceptHandler;
import io.moquette.interception.messages.InterceptPublishMessage;
import io.moquette.server.Server;
import io.moquette.server.config.ClasspathConfig;
import io.moquette.server.config.IConfig;

public class s1 
{

    static class PublisherListener extends AbstractInterceptHandler {
        @Override
        public void onPublish(InterceptPublishMessage message) {
            System.out.println("moquette mqtt broker message intercepted, topic: " + message.getTopicName()
                    + ", content: " + new String(message.getPayload().array()));
        }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        // Creating a MQTT Broker using Moquette
                final IConfig classPathConfig = new ClasspathConfig();

                final Server mqttBroker = new Server();
                final List<? extends InterceptHandler> userHandlers = Arrays.asList(new PublisherListener());
                mqttBroker.startServer(classPathConfig, userHandlers);

                System.out.println("moquette mqtt broker started, press ctrl-c to shutdown..");
                Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        System.out.println("stopping moquette mqtt broker..");
                        mqttBroker.stopServer();
                        System.out.println("moquette mqtt broker stopped");
                    }
                });
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I try to compile, it shows this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't locate the resource "config/moquette.conf"
    at io.moquette.server.config.ClasspathConfig.<init>(ClasspathConfig.java:42)
    at mytest.s1$PublisherListener.main(s1.java:27)
```

I cannot understand this error message. I have already installed mosquito in C:\Program Files (x86)\mosquitto. I have tested it using 
Publisher:

```
mosquitto_pub -m "message from mosquitto_pub client" -t "test"
```

and Subscriber:

```
mosquitto_sub -t "test".
```

Please give me advise to solve this problem.

Comment: The errror is pretty clear, it's saying it can't find the moquette.conf (it's looking in the config directory relative to where you start the app). If you can connect with the command line tools it sounds like you are already running mosquitto as broker so even if you could find the conf file it would likely clash on port 1880 with the other broker

Answer (score 1):

The error is showing because bin, config and lib folder are not added to the Maven project ( read Ready ‘Broker’ part).

Java MQTT lightweight broker: https://github.com/andsel/moquette
Download jar file
https://bintray.com/artifact/download/andsel/generic/distribution-0.10-bundle-tar.tar.gz

Eclipse Paho Java Client:  https://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/java/
Download jar file https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho/org/eclipse/paho/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3/1.0.2/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.0.2.jar

Read this tutorial. http://www.hascode.com/2016/06/playing-around-with-mqtt-and-java-with-moquette-and-eclipse-paho/ Use example code broker and publisher code from here.

```
Ready ‘Broker’ part
1. Create Eclipse maven project.
2.  Download distribution-0.10-bundle-tar.tar.gz from https://bintray.com/artifact/download/andsel/generic/distribution-0.10-bundle-tar.tar.gz
It contains bin, config and lib folder.
3.  Copy these 3 folders in maven project 
4. Compile it.

Ready ‘Publisher’ part
1.  Create Eclipse java project.
2.  Add org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.0.2.jar
3.  Compile it.

Ready ‘Subscriber’ part
1.  Create Eclipse java project.
2.  Add org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.0.2.jar
3.  Compile it.
```

Comment: I am not sure how this is an actual answer to the posted question. Should the be added to the posted question?

Comment: If you follow these steps then there will be no error. The error is showing because bin, config and lib folder are not added to the Maven project.

Comment: Please update your answer with a lead in paragraph about why the error is happening and why these steps will correct the error.